# LWC - Invoke Data Table from the Row Actions of another Data Table

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have requirement to display a data table based on the row actions of another data table through pop-up.

I have done the pop-up through row actions But I am unable to pass the id of the row to the @wire object to get the query and display in the data table.

Please find the JS below.

```
@track currentRecord1 = [] ;

@wire(showGradingSamples, {recordId : '$currentRecord1'})
sampleSeededAcres;
openGradingSample(row)
{
    let currentRecord1 = [] ;
    currentRecord1.push(row.Id);

    showGradingSamples({lstprodId1s: currentRecord1});

    this.isOpenGradingSample = true;

    return currentRecord1;
}
```

How can I pass the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign a value to tracked variable.

```
this.currentRecord1 = [row.Id];
```

This will cause the wire method to dispatch. No need for the local variable or anything else you've done here. You do **not** call wire methods as you would an imperative Apex call.

If you want all the values to be selected cumulatively, you can also:

```
this.currentRecord1 = [...this.currentRecord1, row.Id];
```